# NavBar Submenu Dropdown Won't Show subitems

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having trouble getting my dropdown to display for the "about us" navigation bar menu. My "patient resources" dropdown works perfectly fine so I'm confused why the "about us" doesn't work. I think I'm overlooking a tiny detail probably. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I have inserted the css code under snipet code.)

**ReactJS**

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
 import mainLogo from "../assets/logo/mainLogo.png";
 import menuIcon from "../assets/icon/menuIcon.png";
 import { BsChevronDown } from "react-icons/bs";
 import { FaSistrix } from "react-icons/fa";
 import { Container, Col, Row, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
 import { MyContext } from "../myContext";
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
 import "./navBar.css";

 const pageSubItems = [
"Patient Resources",
"Insurances",
"Patient Portal",
"FAQ",
"Forms",
];
 const aboutSubItems = ["about", "Dr. Isioma Okobah Foundation"];

  function NavBar() {
   const { isSubmenuOpen, setIsSubmenuOpen } = useContext(MyContext);
   const [sideMainNav, setSideMainNav] = useState(false);

   const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
   if (window.scrollY > 50) {
    setScroll(true);
  }
  if (window.scrollY < 50) {
    setScroll(false);
  }
});
}, []);

const handleMouseOver = (e) => {
const value = e.target.textContent;
if (pageSubItems.includes(value) || aboutSubItems.includes(value)) {
  setIsSubmenuOpen(value);
 } else {
  setIsSubmenuOpen("");
 }
 };

   return (
     <>
     <header
        className={`${scroll ? "site-header sticky-header" : "site-header"}`}
        onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
     >
      <Container>
        <Row className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <Col lg={12}>
            <div className="header-box">
              <div className="site-logo">
                <Link to="/">
                  <img src={mainLogo} className="img-logo" />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="header-menu">
                <Nav
                    className={`${
                        sideMainNav
                            ? "main-navigation toggle-nav-menu"
                            : "main-navigation"
                    }`}
                >
                  <button
                      className="toggle-btn"
                      onClick={() => setSideMainNav(!sideMainNav)}
                  >
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul className="header-menu-items">
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li
                        className={`${
                            aboutSubItems.includes(isSubmenuOpen)
                                ? "sub-items show-about"
                                : "sub-items"
                        }`}
                    >
                      <Link to="/about-us">
                        About Us
                        <BsChevronDown
                            style={{
                              paddingLeft: "2px",
                              fontSize: "12px",
                              fontWeight: 500,
                            }}
                        />
                      </Link>
                      <ul className="sub-menu">
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/okobah-foundation">Foundation</Link>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                      <Link to="/services">Services</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li
                        className={`${
                            pageSubItems.includes(isSubmenuOpen)
                                ? "sub-items show-pages"
                                : "sub-items"
                        }`}
                    >
                      <Link to="#">
                        Patient Resources
                        <BsChevronDown
                            style={{
                              paddingLeft: "2px",
                              fontSize: "12px",
                              fontWeight: 500,
                            }}
                        />
                      </Link>
                      <ul className="sub-menu">
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/insurances">Insurances</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/patient-portal">Patient Portal</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/forms">Forms</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/office-policy">Office Policy</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <Link to="/FAQ">FAQ</Link>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
                    </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/contact-us">Contact Us</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </Nav>
            </div>
            <div className="header-search">
              <div className="search-box">
                <div className="search-icon">
                  <a href="#">
                    <FaSistrix />
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="extra-menu">
                <div className="extra-menu-icon">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src={menuIcon} alt="image" />
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  </header>
</>
);
}

export default NavBar;
```

```css
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 30px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 100;
}
.site-header.sticky-header {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(0 0 0/ 10%);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.header-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.site-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
.site-logo a {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-logo {
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.header-menu-items {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header-menu-items li {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
.header-menu-items li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #010f2e;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.header-menu-items li a:hover {
  color: #ff5066;
}
.sub-items .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 60px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  display: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.header-menu-items .sub-items .sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.show-pages .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slide-up;
}
.show-about .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-name: slide-up;
}
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.header-search {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
.search-box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.search-icon a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777777;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.extra-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.extra-menu-icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff5066, #fc9d44, #fc9d44, #ff5066);
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  background-position: left center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px rgb(255 80 102 / 25%);
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.extra-menu-icon a img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.extra-menu-icon:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}
.toggle-btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff5066, #fc9d44);
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
}
.toggle-btn span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 6px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .site-header {
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(0 0 0/10%);
  }

  .site-logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  .toggle-nav-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .toggle-btn span {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff5066, #fc9d44);
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .toggle-btn span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .toggle-btn span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .toggle-btn span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
  }

  .header-menu-items {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -400px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0 30px;
    box-shadow: -30px 0 30px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .header-menu-items {
    transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
  .main-navigation .header-menu-items li {
    display: block;
    margin: -50px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .toggle-nav-menu .header-menu-items li {
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  .header-search {
    display: none;
  }
  .sub-items .sub-menu {
    background-color: #ff50676d;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .header-menu-items .sub-items .sub-menu li {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .header-menu-items li {
    margin: 0 25px;
  }
}
```